# Sum of subgaussian random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^N$ be a set of $\nu$-subgaussian random variables, meaning
$$
\mathbb{E}(\exp(tX_i)) \leq e^{\nu t^2/2}.
$$
Suppose also that $X_i$ are normalized so that $\mathbb{E}(X_i) = 0$
and $\mathbb{E}(X_i^2) = 1$.

Let $a_i$ be a fixed (deterministic) sequence of coefficients, and define the random variables
$$
Y = \sum_{i=1}^N a_i X_i,
$$
and its normalization
$$
Z = \frac{Y}{\sqrt{\mathbb{E} Y^2}}. 
$$
If the $X_i$ are assumed to be independent, then it is not hard to check that $Z$ is also $\nu$-subgaussian, because one can compute its moment generating function.

My question is whether this hypothesis is necessary.

> Is $Z$ a $\nu$-subgaussian random variable, even if $X_i$ are not independent?

The reason one might hope that this is true is that the normalization of $Z$ takes care of any growth of $Z$ that might arise from the dependencies.

My best guess for how to prove this is to bound the joint distribution of $(X_i)$ by a multivariate Gaussian distribution, and then observe that $Y$ is some marginal and is therefore bounded by a Gaussian of the correct variance(?).  But I'm not sure how to fill in the details.

Comment: David Maxen's answer below looks quite good, but you can also refer to Roman Vershynin's "High Dimensional Probability," Proposition 2.6.1 for another proof.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this answers your question but I also stumbled upon this problem, hopefully my solution adds to the discussion for this question.
I am going to first assume $N = 2$, let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be two subgaussian random variables. By definition, we have,
$$ E(\exp{tX_i}) \leq \exp{(t^2\nu_i^2)/2}\ \ \text{for} \ i =1,2.$$
We have $Y = a_1 X_1 + a_2 X_2$. Consider,

$$ E(\exp(tY)) = E(\exp\{ta_1 X_1 + ta_2 X_2\}) = E(\exp{ta_1X_1}\cdot \exp{t a_2 X_2}).$$

Now by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we have,
\begin{align*}
E(\exp{ta_1X_1}\cdot \exp{t a_2 X_2}) &\leq (E(\exp{2ta_1 X_1}))^{1/2} (E(\exp{2ta_2 X_2}))^{-1/2}\\
&\leq \exp{t^2a_1^2 \nu_1^2} \cdot \exp{t^2 a_2^2 \nu_2^2}\\
&= \exp\{t^2 \sum_{i=1}^2 a_i^2 \nu_i^2\},
\end{align*}
where the last inequality was by using the definition of sub-gaussian r.v. $X_1$ and $X_2$. This gives us that $Y \sim SubG(\sum_{i=1}^2 a_i^2 \nu_i^2)$ is also a sub-gaussian random variable. I guess if you normalized $Y$ then the normalizing constant will appear in addition to the $a_1^2$. I think a similar logic could hold for $N$ random variables.

Comment: I guess there is a typo: t should be inside exp() in (exp())?

Comment: You proved that the sum of sub gaussian with parameter Sqrt(2)*(a_1^2*v_1^2+a_2^2*v_2^2)

Answer (score 3):

The answer is yes, a finite linear combination of subgaussian random variables is itself a subgaussian random variable. We will prove this in two parts. Firstly we will show (i) that if $X \sim SG(\nu)$, then $\forall a\in \Bbb R,aX \sim SG(|a|\nu)$. Next, we will show (ii) that if $X_i \sim SG(\nu_i)$ for $i \in [n]$, then $\sum_{i=1}^nX_i \sim SG(\sum_{i=1}^n\nu_i)$. Combining these two results gives
$$\sum_{i=1}^na_iX_i \sim SG(\sum_{i=1}^n|a_i|\nu_i)$$
where $a_i\in \Bbb R$ are constants $ \forall i \in [n]$.

Proof of (i): If $X \sim SG(\nu)$, then $\forall a\in \Bbb R,aX \sim SG(|a|\nu)$. This follows from the definition: $$\Bbb E[\exp(\theta aX)] \le \exp(\theta^2a^2\nu^2/2) = \exp(\theta^2(|a|\nu)^2/2)$$

Proof of (ii): If $X_i \sim SG(\nu_i)$ for $i \in [n]$, then $\sum_{i=1}^nX_i \sim SG(\sum_{i=1}^n\nu_i)$. This uses a generalisation of Hölder's inequality: let $Y_i$ be any real-valued random variables, and let $p_i\in (1, \infty], \sum_{i=1}^n\frac 1{p_i} = 1$. Then
$$\Bbb E\left[\prod_{i=1}^n Y_i\right] \le \prod_{i=1}^n \left(\Bbb E\left[Y_i^{p_i}\right]\right)^{1/p_i}$$
We now begin the proof.
$$
\Bbb E \left[ \exp(\theta \sum_{i=1}^nX_i)\right]
=\Bbb E\left[\prod_{i=1}^n \exp(\theta X_i)\right]\\
\le \prod_{i=1}^n \left(\Bbb E\left[\exp(\theta X_ip_i) \right] \right)^{1/p_i}\\
\le \prod_{i=1}^n \left( \exp(\theta^2 \nu_i^2p_i^2/2) \right)^{1/p_i}\\
= \prod_{i=1}^n \exp(\theta^2 \nu_i^2p_i/2)\\
= \exp \left(\frac{\theta^2}2 \sum_{i=1}^n\nu_i^2p_i \right)
$$
At this point we are nearly done, all that's left is to choose the $p_i$ to get the best possible bound. We take $p_i = \frac{\sum_{j=1}^n\nu_j}{\nu_i}$. Note these satisfy the required conditions: $p_i\in (1, \infty], \sum_{i=1}^n\frac 1{p_i} = 1$. We compute
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n\nu_i^2p_i
= \sum_{i=1}^n\nu_i^2\frac{\sum_{j=1}^n\nu_j}{\nu_i}
= \left(\sum_{i=1}^n\nu_i\right)^2
$$
With which we then conclude
$$
\Bbb E \left[ \exp(\theta \sum_{i=1}^nX_i)\right]
\le \exp \left(\frac{\theta^2}2 \left(\sum_{i=1}^n\nu_i\right)^2 \right)
$$
Namely, $$\sum_{i=1}^nX_i \sim SG(\sum_{i=1}^n\nu_i)$$
Going back to the original question, this proves that Y is subgaussian. That Z is subgaussian follows from property (i).

Comment: If we consider non-centered random variables instead, do we still get that (finite) sums of independent (non-centered) subgaussians are again subgaussian?

Comment: Yes @LSK21, this follows from linearity.