# Pigeonhole for threshold on sum of non-negative random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, random-variables, pigeonhole-principle

Let $X = X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_n$ , where $X_i$ ($1 \le i \le n$) are non negative random variables ($X_i$ are not independent). Then using pigeonhole principle would it be correct to state the following two

$$
\Pr[X \ge t] \le \Pr\bigg[ \bigcup_{i=1}^n\big(X_i \ge \frac{t}{n}\big) \bigg]
$$

$$
\Pr[X \le t] \le \Pr\bigg[ \bigcup_{i=1}^n\big(X_i \le \frac{t}{n}\big) \bigg]
$$

where $t \ge 0$. 
If $X \ge t$, then by pigeonhole principle there will be an $i$ s.t. $X_i \ge \frac{t}{n}$. But the implication is not true in the other direction. 
Similarly for when $X \le t$, there would be an $i$ s.t. $X_i \le \frac{t}{n}$.

If the claim above are correct then I can write

$$
\Pr[X = t] \le \Pr\bigg[ \bigcup_{i=1}^n\big(X_i \ge \frac{t}{n}\big) \bigg]
$$

$$
\Pr[X = t] \le \Pr\bigg[ \bigcup_{i=1}^n\big(X_i \le \frac{t}{n}\big) \bigg]
$$
Which seems fine to me, but bit weird that I can break $\Pr[X=t]$ into two forms one where $X_i \ge \frac{t}{n}$ are involved and another where $X_i \le \frac{t}{n}$.

Comment: The inequalities you wrote (and the proofs of them you gave) are correct; if you elaborate more on your doubt, I think you might get better help. I don't immediately see how you will derive P(X = t) from these inequalities since these bounds are -in general- quite loose.

Comment: @E-A Thank you. Maybe I misworded my question(I'll remove the confusing statements).  But my main doubt remains the same, if the claims were correct. You can convert your comment to an answer I guess.

Comment: You are giving a huge bounty; I think you should get the most out of it regardless of how confusing your doubt is; perhaps you can edit the question further to clarify your doubt instead? (I will happily take the bounty otherwise but I genuinely want to help if I can)

Comment: @E-A I have edited my question.

Comment: @E-A I know in general these bounds are weak, but was working on a question (cannot post its assignment), where I was thinking of using above, then relaxing RHS by union bound ($X_i$ have same distribution and each $X_i$ in turn is sum of independent variables) and then using Chernoff to get some tight bounds. So was just unsure that the above claim I am trying to make was correct or not.

Comment: Your claim is definitely correct; also, you might the answer to the following question relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2517123/sum-of-subgaussian-random-variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Claim and the given argument is correct; a reason why this should still be conceptually OK is because those bounds, in general, are going to be quite loose (especially the final step of going from $P(X \geq t) \geq P(X = t)$ is extremely loose for $X$ continuous, say).